# Using iMessage with my phone number when I don't have an iPhone anymore

Tags: macos, messages

Until recently, I was using iMessage on both iOS and macOS. Now, my phone is dead with a black screen, so I did a full erase from iTunes. ("Find my iPhone" and iCloud was turned off already.)

Currently, I am still able to use iMessage from macOS. My iMessage account is connected only to my phone number, not my email address, and I'd like to keep it that way.

If I don't buy a new iPhone, but a basic phone, can I use my phone number for iMessage on macOS forevermore? Or will this "time out"? What must I do to avoid running into a situation where I will be forced to have an iPhone to continue using iMessage with my phone number?

Comment: I've removed your second question, please ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is not gonna be a timeout. iMessage on macOS has no reason to ask you to log again once you already signed-in.

However, I advise you to link a mail address, because in case your mac gets into trouble, I think you will have a hard time to get everything back with your phone number only.

**Edit:** In that last case, I guess the Apple Support will be your friend.